# How can i return value from Gridview-RowDataBound to use it in link. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Im trying to delete Gridview row on button click. 
i want to save the clicked row's id into a variable. And use this variable in the hyperlink.

here my RowDataBound code

```
  protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.cursor='Pointer';this.style.backgroundColor='Yellow'");
       e.Row.RowIndex.ToString())); 

        string id = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ProductionOrderId").ToString();
    // somthing like
    // return id ;

    }
}
```

here the hyperlink where i need i id of the selected row

```
<asp:HyperLink  runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Producter/Delete?id= id" ID="HyperLink1"> Delete</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Does your hyperlink is defined inside the GridView markup code or is it outside the GridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly:
add a reference to jQuery to the head section of your Master page

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Secondly:
add the ProductionOrderId to the datarow as an attribute (as shown below), this way it will be accessible on the client side via jQuery

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.cursor='Pointer';this.style.backgroundColor='Yellow'");
                e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
                string id = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ProductionOrderId").ToString();
                //save ProductionOrderId as datarow attribute
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("rowid", id);
            }
}
```

Thirdly:

in the body of your .aspx file add the following script tag.
Every time a row is clicked it modifies your 'Delete' link with the id of the row to delete. I have also included your link for the sake of clarity and completeness.

```
<a href='<%=ResolveUrl("~/Producter/Delete?id=" ) %>' ID="HyperLink1">Delete</a>

 <script language="javascript">
    //every time a row is clicked this script will perform the following actions:
        $("tr").click(function () {
            var clicked = $(this);
            //get the row id from the currently cliked row
            var rowid = clicked.attr("rowid");
            //get the value of href attribute from the link with id 'HyperLink1'
            var link = $("#HyperLink1").attr("href");
            //remove any previously appended values
            var linkTokens = link.split("=");
            linkTokens[1] = "";
            link = linkTokens.join("=");
            //append the current row id to the link
            link = link + rowid;
            //set the href attribute of your link to the new value
            $("#HyperLink1").attr("href", link);
        });
    </script>
```

Should you need further assistance please do not hesitate to let me know.

Disclaimer:
It is usually best to use a cdn to deliver js files since it is highly likely that they have already been cached by the user browser.

As requested, here is how to put jquery library 2.0 in your content folder:

1. Make a backup of your working solution.
2. Click on  [this link](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js) with your right mouse button and choose
   save as.
3. Save it to your content folder on disk.
4. From Visual studio choose 'add existing item'
5. Browse to your content folder
6. Select your jquery file
7. Click add.
8. Now Drag your jquery file in the header section of your page.
9. Delete the old  tag (link to ajax.googleapis.com)

Comment: i got the id=9 all the time, even if no row is clicked:

Comment: it still has 9 all the time. when i run the program, i put the mouse over "Delete" and i se the link in the status bar and id=9. Nothing changing when click !

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll update my answer asap, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Have you got any solution ?

Comment: Updated my answer, sorry about the previous misunderstanding let me know whether it meets your requirements.

Comment: I dont have master page, i run Aspx page:
Where to place this 

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  ?

Comment: in the head section of your page, namely between the <head> </head> tags.

Comment: i placed it, put the source is undelined. file not found

Comment: it will be downloaded at runtime from google cdn (content delivery network), it is not a problem

Comment: can i download it and put it im my content folder ?

Comment: im givin up, have tryied to get functionality to work i three dayes.

Comment: no wait you're there, try and run the solution i gave you please, give it a try!

Comment: btw if you still want to download jquery:
use this link http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js
and then place t in your contents folder.
obviously you'll have to update this link  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script> to point to your content folder

Comment: YEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEES ITTTTTTTTTTTTT WOOOOOOOOOOOOORKS FINAAAAAAAAAALY

Comment: but the last quastion pleeeaase
Can i plase the js code i seperate folder ?:
im using MVC and dont want to much code in the view

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me throughout this, best of luck with your next endeavour!

Comment: but the last quastion pleeeaase Can i place the js code i seperate folder ?: im using MVC and dont want to much code in the view

Comment: see edited answer, what js code are you referring to? the script block? If that is the case just copy and paste its contents into a js file and include it AFTER the jquery script tag in the header.

Answer (score 1):

Modified the RowDataBound to hold the GridView record ids to the client side:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.cursor='Pointer';this.style.backgroundColor='Yellow'");
       e.Row.RowIndex.ToString())); 

        string id = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ProductionOrderId").ToString();

        // store the id at the client side
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("id", id);
    }
}
```

And in your javascript code (using jQuery): This will change the hyperlink href value whenever the GridView record would be clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> tr[id]').click(function () {
      idToDelete = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> tr[id]').val();
      $("a.HyperLink1").attr("href", "~/Producter/Delete?id=" + idToDelete);
  });
</script>
```

Although I haven't tested the code, but I hope it should work as required.

**EDIT:**
You should also have added reference for jQuery.js file in the head section like this:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: can y make me help and tell me where to place the javascript code in ASPX page ?

Comment: Any where inside the <script type="text/javascript"> block. But as this code using jQuery, you shoud have added reference to jQuery.js file.

Comment: Any version. But obviously the latest one would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to create a helper method:

```
string getLink(MyObject obj)
{
   return "~/Producter/Delete?id" + obj.ID;
}
```

And in the view:

```
<asp:HyperLink  runat="server" NavigateUrl="<%# getLink(Container.DataItem) %>" ID="HyperLink1"> Delete</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: what is Myobject in this case ?
i want the id of the row that selected by mouseclick

Comment: I suppose you're binding a list of objects to the gridview. In this case this would be one instance of the list. Since your code doesn't mention your binding I assumed you're binding to a List<MyObject>. But you should fill in the actual class